# Difference between .config and kconfig

Tags: linux-kernel

I am new to the kernel configuration and trying to understand the difference between these two terms:

- .config
- Kconfig

My understanding about .config is that it contains the information about configuration which is being used while compiling the kernel. What is the role of Kconfig then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, The Kconfig files contain text that gets printed out when you ask for help while configuring a kernel. Your configuration choices go in the .config file.

> The Kconfig files describe: the configuration symbols supported in the
>   build system, the logical organization and structure to group the
>   symbols in menus and sub-menus, and the relationships between the
>   different configuration symbols that govern the valid configuration
>   combinations.
>   [The Kconfig File Structure](http://docs.zephyrproject.org/1.4.0/reference/kbuild/kbuild_kconfig.html)